# In regards to DAO classic withdrawl

Tags: the-dao

Is there any information regarding the process to claim the DAO classic. I hold ETH in my mist wallet and would like to know if I need to sync ETC chain, is there any concerns regarding replay attack or has this issue been resolved? 
The information I am finding explains how to execute a split contract in mist but I am not sure if this process is relevant to the ETH that was withdrawn from DAO. I held ETH during the HF on Polo so I believe I have a ETC address there as well.Thanks you.

Comment: I'll be updating http://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/8338/how-do-i-convert-my-the-dao-tokens-into-ethers-on-the-ethereum-classic-chain when more information is available.