# How Do I Know If I Still Have Remaining DAO Refunds?

Tags: ether, the-dao, thedao-refund

I purchased a small amount of DAO contracts last June. I followed articles on how to retrieve them on and off, and I may have acted on some of the instructions posted. However, because the whole process baffles me, I'm not sure if I did it or not. How can I find out if I still have DAO's left to retrieve?

Following the recommendation below to use Mist (why is my version displayed as Ethereum Wallet anyway?), I obtain the following screenshot[image]

I'm not clear if that tells me that I have already retrieved my token from the DAO or I still have a balance in there.

Comment: Are we still able to withdrawal from the DAO extrabalance? Could you let me know if I am eligible? 0x7B78de0986270Af9C40BcbAa7b2FFAE18c333746

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The OP asked about determining if one still had DAO available to refund. The instructions are at https://theethereum.wiki/w/index.php/The_DAO_Refunds#How_Do_I_Check_If_My_Account_Has_Any_Remaining_The_DAO_Refund_Due

Answer (score 2):

Do you know your Ethereum wallet address or have it entered in Mist?

If so, you can install/open Mist, go to the Contracts section, and then at the bottom of that page select "Watch Token" and enter token number: 0xbb9bc244d798123fde783fcc1c72d3bb8c189413

If you do not have an Ethereum wallet address, you'd need to track that down before you could find out.

[image]

Comment: I do have my Ethereum wallet address

Comment: This is where I start getting confused; I have Ethereum Wallet installed, is this what you are calling Mist?

Comment: Most likely yes, you are talking about Mist.  Here is the link to download the latest version: https://github.com/ethereum/mist/releases.  Edit: I've added a picture of the basic interface to my post above, and highlighted the section you need to visit to enter the token address.

Comment: Your screenshot is identical to mine with the exception that the name of your application is "Mist" and mine is mine is "Ethereum Wallet". Your leftmost menu selections is Mist and mine is "Ethereum Wallet", while the other selections are identical: Accounts, Edit, View, Develop, Window Help; I wonder why, because I downloaded yesterday the latest release 0.8.9, so shouldn't they be identical? I followed your steps, and updated with my screenshot. Thanks for your help.

Comment: After I go to the Contracts section, select "Watch Token" and enter the DAO token number, what am I supposed to see or not see that tells me if I still have DAO to retrieve?

Comment: what's next, once I have entered the token with the DAO?

Answer (score 2):

#### Update Mar 24 2017

Detailed updated instructions at https://theethereum.wiki/w/index.php/The_DAO_Refunds .

---

Latest information at https://medium.com/curator-multisig-phf-official-channel/dao-token-holders-come-claim-your-money-b428f186572a#.cj95ba858 .

## Easiest Method - MyEtherWallet v3.3.7

You will need to download MyEtherWallet v3.3.7 onto your local machine:

- Go to https://github.com/kvhnuke/etherwallet/releases/tag/v3.3.7
- Click on `dist-v3.3.7.zip`
- Unzip it and open the folder
- Double-click `index.html`

At the bottom of the page, click on Withdraw DAO:
[image]

You will have to either:

- Enter your private key, or
- Upload your keystore file (UTC / JSON) and enter your password to unlock the keystore file.

You will see the following page:
[image]

In the red box on the left, your balance will display if you have any refunds left to claim.

To claim the refunds, select the tab in the red box near the top:

- Withdraw DAO For ETC
- Withdraw DAO For ETH
- Withdraw extraBalance

Note that the time limit for the **Withdraw DAO For ETC** is Apr 15 2017. The **Withdraw DAO for ETH** and **Withdraw extraBalance** have no time limits.

Further detailed information:

- [How do I convert my The DAO tokens into ethers using the withdrawal contract after the hard fork?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/7204/how-do-i-convert-my-the-dao-tokens-into-ethers-using-the-withdrawal-contract-aft)
- [How do I get a refund for the amount I paid in excess of 1 ether to 100 The DAO tokens](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/7265/how-do-i-get-a-refund-for-the-amount-i-paid-in-excess-of-1-ether-to-100-the-dao)
- [How do I convert my The DAO tokens into ethers on the Ethereum Classic chain?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/8338/how-do-i-convert-my-the-dao-tokens-into-ethers-on-the-ethereum-classic-chain)

Comment: The curator.com address updated above with title Latest information athttps://theethereum.wiki/w/index.php/The_DAO_Refunds

Comment: Continuing comment above - The curator.com address updated above with title "Latest information at", points to the original address given. https://theethereum.wiki/w/index.php/The_DAO_Refunds. The reading is quite involved, starting from the section to check what type of refunds one is entitled to. Eventually, because MyEtherWallet does not have a link for DAO refunds anymore, a search in MyEtherWallet own knowledge base goes to step by step instructions at https://myetherwallet.github.io/knowledge-base/faq/withdrawing-dao-tokens.html