# Can I call contract function (balanceOf) based on block number?

Tags: web3js, tokens, blocks

I want to check the DAO balance address in the specify time(block number)
Is it possible to specify the block number when calling a contract function in web3.

```
var contract = web3.eth.contract(abi).at(“0xbb9bc244d798123fde783fcc1c72d3bb8c189413″);        
contract.balanceOf(eth.coinbase);
```

Answer (score 1):

The format the statement to get the `contract.balanceOf(...)` value is:

```
var preHardForkBlock = 1919999;
var daosPreHardFork = theDAO.balanceOf(address, preHardForkBlock);
```

See [How can I verify that my The DAO token balance is correct when the Goodies provide an ETC refund on the Ethereum Classic chain?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/8071/1268) for a working example.